# Loop array foreach and add further array values per group?

Tags: php, arrays

## for each Example 1 caption and 3 occurrences for the source map

What am I doing wrong?

**Images Array**

```php
$imgsArray = array(
  'image1-small.jpg', 'image1-medium.jpg', 'image1-large.jpg',
  'image2-small.jpg', 'image2-medium.jpg', 'image2-large.jpg',
  'image3-small.jpg', 'image3-medium.jpg', 'image3-large.jpg'
); // sometimes more pictures too
```

**Captions Array**

```php
$imgCaption = array('Adam','Peter','Susi');
```

**the code**

```php
foreach($imgsArray as $files => $img) {
  $first_char = substr($img,0,strpos($img,"-")); // delete from hyphen to the last string
  if ($first_char != $last_entry) {
  echo '<p>This is '.$imgCaption[$files];
  echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>'.$first_char.'-small.jpg</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$first_char.'-medium.jpg</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$first_char.'-large.jpg</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$imgCaption[$files].'</li>';
  echo '</ul>';
  echo '<i>Ciao, '.$imgCaption[$files].'</i><br>---</p>';
  }
  $last_entry = $first_char;
}
```

**unexpected**

This is Adam

- image1-small.jpg
- image1-medium.jpg
- image1-large.jpg
- Adam

*Ciao, Adam*
---

This is *Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in...*

- image2-small.jpg
- image2-medium.jpg
- image2-large.jpg
- *Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in...*

*Ciao, *Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in...*
---*

This is *Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in...*

- image3-small.jpg
- image3-medium.jpg
- image3-large.jpg
- *Notice:  Undefined offset: 6 in...*

Ciao, Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in...
---

**expected**

This is Adam

- image1-small.jpg
- image1-medium.jpg
- image1-large.jpg
- Adam

Ciao, Adam
---

This is Peter

- image2-small.jpg
- image2-medium.jpg
- image2-large.jpg
- Peter

Ciao, Peter
---

This is Susi

- image3-small.jpg
- image3-medium.jpg
- image3-large.jpg
- Susi

Ciao, Susi
---

Comment: Something just to check - why do you have all the values in `$imgsArray` and then ignore most of them and add what looks like the same extension in the loop?

Comment: I have simplified the question. the image groups are actually under <img> tags (depending on the resolution) and each image group also has caption

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that using the index to the `$imgsArray` for the `$imgCaption` array isn't going to work.

The easy fix is to just keep track of how many times you put out the text and increment it each time (`$textCount` in this example) ...

```
$textCount = 0;
$last_entry = '';
foreach($imgsArray as $files => $img) {
    $first_char = substr($img,0,strpos($img,"-")); // delete from hyphen to the last string
    if ($first_char != $last_entry) {
        echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li>'.$first_char.'-small.jpg</li>';
        echo '<li>'.$first_char.'-medium.jpg</li>';
        echo '<li>'.$first_char.'-large.jpg</li>';
        echo '<li>'.$imgCaption[$textCount++].'</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    $last_entry = $first_char;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but to avoid abuses I took $imgArray names instead of numbers - $imgCaption = array('Adam','Peter','Susi');

Comment: OK, not sure what difference that makes, this code just move on to the next element in `$imgCaption` each time the name changes in `$imgArray`.

Comment: You're right! Thank you for your answer. Best regards from Vienna

Comment: I have simplified the question. the image groups are actually under <img> tags (depending on the resolution) and each image group also has caption

Answer (score 1):

If you always have one caption for 3 images you might want to consider a numerically indexed loop:

```
$imgsArray = array(
  'image1-small.jpg', 'image1-medium.jpg', 'image1-large.jpg',
  'image2-small.jpg', 'image2-medium.jpg', 'image2-large.jpg',
  'image3-small.jpg', 'image3-medium.jpg', 'image3-large.jpg'
);

$imgCaption = array('Adam','Peter','Susi');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($imgCaption); $i++) {
    echo '<p>This is '.$imgCaption[$i];
    echo "<ul>\n";
    for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
        echo '<li>' . $imgsArray[$i * 3 + $j] . "</li>\n";
    }
    echo "<li>{$imgCaption[$i]}</li>\n";
    echo "</ul>\n";
    echo '<i>Ciao, '.$imgCaption[$i].'</i><br>---</p>';
}
```

Output:

This is Adam

- image1-small.jpg
- image1-medium.jpg
- image1-large.jpg
- Adam

*Ciao, Adam*
---

This is Peter

- image2-small.jpg
- image2-medium.jpg
- image2-large.jpg
- Peter

*Ciao, Peter*
---

This is Susi

- image3-small.jpg
- image3-medium.jpg
- image3-large.jpg
- Susi

*Ciao, Susi*
---

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/JEp6D)

Comment: I have simplified the question. the image groups are actually under <img> tags (depending on the resolution) and each image group also has caption

Comment: We can only answer the question you have posted. That calls for unordered lists, which this (and Nigel's answer) produce. I've updated my answer to reflect your expected output

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Best regards from Vienna!

Comment: @CemFirat not sure what you mean by that. This code is simply outputting the image names that exist in the array. I think it would be good if you updated the question to better reflect your actual code, it would make it a lot easier to give you a solution that you can then make work in your environment.